# res/ directory tree

Tags: java, android

I'm going through some book which tries to teach android development. In the book, the author outlines some of the directories found under res/. He mentions res/menu which holds XML based menu specifications. He also makes mention of res/raw which holds "general-purpose files." These folders were not created when I created a new android project. I'm using the latest Android SDK with the latest Eclipse version. Are those folders he mentions from some older version of the android SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create those folder's when you need them, they aren't automatically created. If you create a folder in res called raw, ant will pick it up and use it accordingly.

Comment: Is ant the android sdk compiler tool that's included in my IDE if I happen to be using eclipse with ADT?

Comment: Ant automates builds for you, if you're using Eclipse with the Google ADT plugin then you're using Ant. http://ant.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

You really dont *need* them, but if you do decide to use them, just create a new folder and call it that, it will work fine.

Comment: Another question (may belong in its own post): I always seem to have an error popping up in the console when I start new projects. The error is always that the project cannot open the class file "r.java" - no such file or directory. But I know that file is there and the project automatically created it. What gives?

Comment: It will always report the error, and a couple of seconds later when it finishes loading the error will go away.
The only time r.java isnt generated is when you have an error in your resources.